# Build a matrix of comparisons out of two vectors in python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, vector, absolute

I have two vectors `a` and `b` and would like to compare each element in `a` with each element in `b`. As a measure of comparison, I would like to use the [absolute difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs).

What is the best way to do that, meaning **without** a nested/double loop?

Illustration:

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = [4,5,6]

calculation idea:
    1  2  3 

4   3  2  1
5   4  3  2
6   5  4  3

resulting matrix:
3  2  1
4  3  2
5  4  3
```

How is such a calculation called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
```

Using outer:

```
np.subtract.outer(b,a)
```

using broadcasting:

```
b[:,None]-a
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you happen to know how this operation would be called?

Comment: @User12547645 I did write their names. You can google `outer in python` or `broadcasting in python` and you will get more information about the two